# What servers are public and private whjat servsers are used how it works

Tags: database, tomcat, amazon-ec2, server-side, devops

I need to understand how 3tier web applicaiton servers work and what all servers made access to public and private ?

What servers are public and private whjat servsers are used how it works

Comment: this is a very vague question! Can you be more specific about what you understand already and need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Public server has an external IP address and can be accessed from the Internet directly. Private server is placed to private network, have no direct Internet access and by default can be accessed from this private network only. 
In AWS terms, private subnet is the subnet with NAT gateway (ot host) where all traffic is routed instead of internet gateway (IGW) for public subnets and external addresses assignment disabled by default.